# passing text entered in a textbox to three other pages

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create three pages that when a name is entered in a text box and the button is clicked to the next page, it will ask to confirm if the name entered is correct and to click the next button to go to the last page.  The text entered should transfer or pass from the first page, to the second, then the third.  I have to use "hidden" as well as "header" as well as "POST" in the code.

here is what I have on page one so far:

```
<? $things = array('one thing', 'two thing'); ?>




<form action= "page1.php" method="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT"  name="textbox">


    <input type='hidden' name='secret' value=96>
<input type='hidden' name='stuff' value='<?= urlencode(serialize($things)) ?> ' >
<input type='submit' name='submit_btn'>
</form>
```

This is what I got on the next page:

```
<?php
echo "Click next if your name is " . $_POST['textbox'];
  ?>
 <form action= "page2.php" method="POST"> 
<input type='hidden' name='secret' value=96>
<input type='hidden' name='stuff' value='<?= urlencode(serialize($things)) ?> ' >
<input type='submit' name='next' value ="next">
</form>
```

and this is what i got on the last page... please help!  thank you!

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action= "page1.php" method="POST"> 
        <?php
        echo "Finally! Welcome " . $_POST['textbox'];
        ?>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you have an error? A problem? Precise your question please.

Comment: Why not use sessions? [http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions]

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a form on the last page if there is no input to send?

**Also, in the first line it should be:**

```
<?php $things = array('one thing', 'two thing');?>
```

**It should be like:**

```
<?php $things = array('one thing', 'two thing'); ?>

<form action= "page1.php" method="POST">
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT"  name="textbox">


    <input type='hidden' name='secret' value=96>
<input type='hidden' name='stuff' value='<?= urlencode(serialize($things)) ?> ' >
<input type='submit' name='submit_btn'>
</form>
```

**page1.php**

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo "Finally! Welcome " . $_POST['textbox'];
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTH.

Comment: LOL, not sure, this whole form thing is foreign to me so thanks for your patience and help.  I think the reason why I used it is to pull the information from the first page where the original location was inputted at.

Comment: also the page had an error and didnt display my second page so I updated the post.  TY!

Comment: I tried your code on my last page which is actually page2.php not page1.php...  any way it displays:


**Notice: Undefined index: textbox in C:\xampp\htdocs\lab14_q2test\page2.php on line 14
Finally! Welcome** 

it should read:

**Finally! Welcome "text that was entered in text box on first page"**